# How to do this program in C? Part 3.0

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, scanf

Write a function called readRect() that uses scanf() to read the values defining the
position of a rectangle. The values are integers in the order xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax. Your
function should pass the parameters by reference to return these four integer values. Moreover, your function is to return an integer that is the number of values successfully scanned so the user can type a nonnumeric item such as eod to indicate no data (i.e., use the return type to return this value).
I don't understand how I should create the function readRect() so that it passes the parameters by reference

```
int readRect (int w, int x, int y, int z){
     return scanf("%d%d%d%d\n",&w,&x,&y,&z);
}



int main (void){
    int a,b,c,d;
    printf(">>enter two rectangles:\n");
    readRect(a,b,c,d);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it as

```
int readRect (int *w, int *x, int *y, int *z)  
{
      return scanf("%d%d%d%d",w,x,y,z);  
}
```

and call it from `manin` as

```
readRect(&a, &b, &c, &d);
```

Note that, in C, **all the calls are by value and not by reference**.

Comment: why does it scan for 8 values before termination when I only used the readRect() in the main once?

Comment: @user2805620; Romove `\n` from `scanf`

Comment: Can you tell me why though? I don't just want to know that that's what you do for it to not scan.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the parameters by address, aka pointers.  So, the function header will be:

```
int readRect ( int * w, int * x, int * y, int * z )
```

and the call from `main` will be

```
readRect ( &a, &b, &c, &d );
```